# Snap mouse cursor to center of screen

Tags: autohotkey

When F4 is pressed I'm attempting to snap the cursor to center of screen. Here is what I'm trying :

```
F4::
x := (A_ScreenWidth / 2)
y := (A_ScreenHeight / 2)
mousemove, x, y
return
```

But when I run this script the mouse position moves on opening and when press F4 the mouse does not moves position ?

Comment: What's with the double `'/'`?

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl question updated but same issue. I used some of this code from another example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Persistent ;//keeps script running
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
Return ;//stops auto execution

F4:: ;//your code
x := (A_ScreenWidth / 2)
y := (A_ScreenHeight / 2)
mousemove, x, y
return
```

Without **#Persistent**, script would close after executing all the lines of code.

Autohotkey executes every line of code until the first "**Return**".

**CoordMode** line will ensure the mouse movement is relative to the screen as opposed to the active window (credit: @user3419297)

Toodles

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: Done. My amendment has explanation

Comment: @KickAss can you help me too plz ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76742580/cant-use-multiple-keys-at-the-same-time?noredirect=1#comment135298261_76742580

Answer (score 4):

```
F4::
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen  ; If this command is not used, the coordinates are relative to the active window.
x := (A_ScreenWidth / 2)
y := (A_ScreenHeight / 2)
mousemove, x, y
return
```

http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm#Remarks

Answer (score 0):

[Nircmd by Nir Sofer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) has the following option:

```
nircmd setcursor x y
```

You can create a shortcut to this command line and assign any hotkey to it. There are a lot of other options for mouse cursor as detailed in the nircmd.chm file.