# Cant use multiple keys at the same time

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to work on a script in which when I press the "q" key it should put the mouse cursor to the center of the screen but I want to use this hot key with any other key.
For Example, I have pinned 5 keys at the same time so it should register the hot key but it won't. My script currently looks like this:

```
  q::
    MouseMove, 680,385
    Return
```

Edit for those who still don't understand:

I want a script that if I press a single key, for example, "q" then it should move the cursor of the mouse to the center. Now I don't only want to press the "q" key but with it also other keys.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please do edit it so that it's clear what exactly you need.

Comment: @user3419297 I have explained it in simple terms for you :)

Comment: Still not clear. Do you mean in a two-key-combination with other keys like q+a, q+b etc.? For what purpose? The purpose is important for the code constuction.

Comment: @user3419297 do you have discord, I can explain it there?

Comment: If it is for a game, I'm not the right contact person.

Comment: but can't you help me a little bit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254628/discussion-between-user3419297-and-mike-osborn).

Comment: Bruh r u still there, ur afk?

Comment: @user3419297 sorry, can u help me again?

Answer (score 0):

*The provided code is in `AHKv2` syntax.*

You may achieve this by using trigger absent `Hotstring`s.
I.e., add an `*` to the tags section of a hotstring so that it does not need an ending character such as `Space` on `Enter` to be triggered:

```
:*:q::
{
  MouseMove(680, 385)
}
```

This approach has its incoveniences, so I encourage using `#HotIfWinActive`   so that the hotstrings do not bother you outside of the game you may be playing.

---

The `Hotkey` approach is not possible since there is ambiguity when it comes to interpret trigger sequences when several keys are pressed at once.
For example, if you press `a + b + q`, the number of ways to interpret this combination is equal to the number of different partitions for the set `{a, b, c}`. In order to eliminate any ambiguity, the whole combination is interpreted as a hotkey.